# How to reject/delete/close a phabricator patch

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I have a patch which I want to close and hide in my project without landing it myself or let others to land it later on. This patch is just obsolete.

Is there any way to close/delete/reject this? I think so, because on [their website](http://phabricator.org/) it says:

> You can reject code if you don't like it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use the "Abandon" option in the "Add Comment" section to close revisions you no longer intend to pursue.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out already, didn't know that I need to commandeer the revision before I can do it.

Comment: 'Abandon' is an option in the "Add Comment" section at the bottom of the page.

Comment: how to abandon revsion diff

Comment: Would have been nice to have this in the top right "Actions" section of the page.

Comment: I'm new to Phabricator. I'd say this is a very bad UX! I spent 10min to find it in a long diff. Phabricator is straight out of 90's. P.S, `On May 29, 2021, Phacility announced that it was ceasing operations and no longer maintaining Phabricator.`

Answer (score 14):

Use the "Abandon" option in the "Add comment" section at the bottom of the page.